# how to format a partition containing Master boot record in Linux 12.10?

Tags: format, mbr

few days ago I have installed Linux 12.10 in my 16 GB USB drive. It was working fine. After some days, I wanted USB for my other uses, so I tried to format it. Whole USB gets formatted but the partition of 8 GB containing **Master Boot Record** didn't. So, now USB drive showing me only 8 GB of free space. Please help me soon.
  I have windows 7 on my hard disk also.

Answer (score 2):

Search for disk in dash, and click on it.  and follow the images below.

Make sure that the disk is unmounted to be be able to complete the tasks.

[image]

Click on the little wheels on the to right corner, and choose format disk.  That will setup the partition

[image]

Then click on the little wheels as shown below, and choose format to get the flash drive ready for use.  It creates the file system.

[image]